# Call a function / subroutine only once every X iterations in Fortran

Tags: function, fortran, call, subroutine

I have a fortran code where, amongst other things, I put some values like temperature and call a subroutine.

This subroutine gives me back a radiation solution that is then used for new iterations.

The problem is that this subroutine takes a lot of time to process, so I wish to call it only once every, say, twenty iterations and keep the last solution for the rest of the program until then.

Is there a viable way of doing this?

Comment: Formatting, remove thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply do just

```
  n_iterations = 100000
  nth = 20

  do i = 1, n_iterations
    if (mod(i, nth)==0) call my_subroutine
  end do
```

expression `mod(i, nth)==0` is true only if `i` can be divided by `nth` with zero remainder.

Comment: Thank you very much. One thing, I don't know for sure how many iterations it will take for convergence, can I put an arbitrary number like 100000 regardless? I am just guessing here that the actual number will be much lower.

Comment: There are various types of loops in Fortran and various ways how to exit them. It is totally up to you. My answer just uses `i` as a counter. You can have a counter even in a `do while` loop, just increase it by one at every iteration yourself.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to use nested loops:

```
       do i = 1,bignum
         do j = i,20
            code to be repeated many times
         end do
         call subroutine_to_be_called_ocasionally()
       end do
```